# Can't post file data to server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I've got a kendo upload control to select the file defined in my cshtml as:

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                .Name("employeeDocument")
                .Messages(m => m.Select("Select"))
                .Multiple(false)
                .Events(e => e.Select("onSelect"))
                .Validation(validatoin => validatoin.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".pdf", ".htm", ".html", ".eml", ".msg" })))
```

Then in javascript in the same cshtml file I have:

```
var fileData = null;

function onSelect(e)
{
    fileData = e.files[0];
}
    
function onClickUploadEmployeeDocument(e)
{
    var formData =
    {
        employeeDocumentFile: fileData,
        employeeId: $("#EmployeeId").val(),
        fiscalPeriodId: $("#FiscalPeriodId").val()
    };

    console.log(formData);

    var _url = "/Statement/EmployeeDocumentUpload?handler=FileUpload";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: formData,
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        success: function (response)
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                window.parent.$("#employeeFileUploadWnd").data("kendoWindow").close();
                window.parent.rebindEmployeeDocumentsGrid();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

I know the problem is with trying to include fileData in formData. If I remove that property it hits the server just fine, however I have no file data.

The errors I get when `onClickUploadEmployeeDocument` fires is:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:72390)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72282)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72305)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72305)
    at k.param (jquery.min.js:2:72601)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2:75981)
    at init.onClickUploadEmployeeDocument (EmployeeDocumentUpload?employeeId=4430&fiscalPeriodId=3:90:11)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:164:37)
    at init._click (kendo.all.js:30687:54)
    at HTMLSpanElement.i (jquery.min.js:2:87485)
```

and:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation
    at i (jquery.min.js:2:72390)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72282)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72305)
    at qt (jquery.min.js:2:72305)
    at k.param (jquery.min.js:2:72601)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:2:75981)
    at init.onClickUploadEmployeeDocument (EmployeeDocumentUpload?employeeId=4430&fiscalPeriodId=3:90:11)
    at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:164:37)
    at init._click (kendo.all.js:30687:54)
    at HTMLSpanElement.i (jquery.min.js:2:87485)
```

From the `console.log(formData)` line I can see that the file data is being properly captured.

How do I send the file data to the server along with the other two parameters?

For completion's sake here is the server side code:

```
    public JsonResult OnPostFileUpload(IFormFile employeeDocumentFile, int employeeId, int fiscalPeriodId)
    {
        bool isSuccess = DLStatement.SaveEmployeeDocument(employeeDocumentFile, employeeId, fiscalPeriodId, User.Identity.Name);

        return new JsonResult(new { success = isSuccess });
    }
```

EDIT --

I've tried some other configurations but no success. I've also eliminated the two parameters (`employeeId` and `fiscalPeriodId`) I was attempting to send along with the file, so now I'm only trying to send the file.

1. using `FormData()`

   ```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('employeeDocumentFile', document.getElementById('employeeDocument').files[0]);
   ```

and

```
var fileData = null;

function onSelect(e)
{
    fileData = e.files[0];
}

//excerpt from onClickUploadEmployeeDocument
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('employeeDocumentFile', fileData);
```

I also updated the ajax request to set `processData` and `contentType` to false.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: formData,
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response)
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                window.parent.$("#employeeFileUploadWnd").data("kendoWindow").close();
                window.parent.rebindEmployeeDocumentsGrid();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
        }
    });
```

I either get a 400 bad request or I reach the server but the file isn't captured so `IFormFile` is null. Using `console.log(fileData)` does show that the file is being captured client side.

I also tried getting rid of ajax and submitting the form.

```
<form id="formEmployeeDocument" class="ct-small-popup__form" method="POST">
    <div class="ct-small-popup__field-container">
        <div class="ct-small-popup__field ct-small-popup__field--width100 ct-small-popup__field--flex-column">
            <div class="ct-small-popup__field-information-container ct-small-popup__field-information-container--width365">
                @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                    .Name("employeeDocument")
                    .Messages(m => m.Select("Select"))
                    .Multiple(false)
                    .Events(e => e.Select("onSelect"))
                    .Validation(validatoin => validatoin.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".pdf", ".htm", ".html", ".eml", ".msg" }))
                    )
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="hidUpload" style="display:none" />
</form>

function onClickUploadEmployeeDocument(e)
{
    $('#hidUpload').click();
}
```

This just refreshes the page and does not hit the server.

Comment: You are using a HTTP Request.  An upload is a MIME attachment in the body of the request.  Instead you are sending in the body of the Request a application/json.  You are getting an error because the server is trying to process the body as a MIME attachment and you are sending JSON.

Comment: @jdweng Do I just need to specify the content type somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried adding this in ajax: `contentType: false, processData: false`?

Comment: @Chen Yes. I also tried using `FormData()` and append. Depending on how I configure things I either get response 400 or I successfully hit the server, but server doesn't receive the file, just null.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working demo, you can refer to it.

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public JsonResult OnPostFileUpload(IFormFile employeeDocumentFile, int employeeId, int fiscalPeriodId)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { success = "succcess" });
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions {
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken;
    }
}
<div>
    <input type="number" id="EmployeeId" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="number" id="FiscalPeriodId" />
</div>
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("employeeDocument")
        .Messages(m => m.Select("Select"))
        .Multiple(false)
        .Events(events => events.Select("onSelect"))
        .Validation(validatoin => validatoin.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".pdf", ".htm", ".html", ".eml", ".msg" })))
</div>
<div>
    <button onclick="onClickUploadEmployeeDocument()">Submit</button>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        var fileData = null;

        function onSelect(e) {
            fileData = e.files[0].rawFile;
        }

        function onClickUploadEmployeeDocument(e) {
            var formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('employeeId', $("#EmployeeId").val())
            formData.append('fiscalPeriodId', $("#FiscalPeriodId").val())
            formData.append('employeeDocumentFile', fileData)

            console.log(formData);

            //var _url = "/Statement/EmployeeDocumentUpload?handler=FileUpload";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Index?handler=FileUpload",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()' },
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        window.parent.$("#employeeFileUploadWnd").data("kendoWindow").close();
                        window.parent.rebindEmployeeDocumentsGrid();
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

The 400 error may be caused by `RequestVerificationToken`, you can refer to my code above.

If you use `fileData = e.files[0]` directly, you will not get the file data, because the `rawFile` attribute saves the actual file data.